# css: margin not working after inline elements line break

Tags: css, margin, line-breaks

```css
.tag-area {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tag-area a.tag-item {
  min-width: 60px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(42, 154, 191);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tag-area a.tag-item span {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #eee;
}

.tag-area a.tag-item:hover {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-area">
  <a class="tag-item" href="/tags/30/">o11 <span>×3</span></a>
  <a class="tag-item" href="/tags/3/">rest <span>×3</span></a>
  <a class="tag-item" href="/tags/9/">foot <span>×1</span></a>
  <a class="tag-item" href="/tags/12/">decide <span>×1</span></a>
  <a class="tag-item" href="/tags/14/">whether <span>×1</span></a>
  <a class="tag-item" href="/tags/15/">possible <span>×1</span></a>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a little gap above the last two tags, but why `margin-top` property on tag does not work?

Comment: `<a>` and `<span>` are inline-elements they are "mushy" add `display: inline-block` to `<a>` and `<span>`

Comment: @zer00ne, appreciate it, cheers.